# What's the origin of the phrase "Rise Up Singing"?

Tags: lyrics, folk

There's a famous song book called "[Rise Up Singing](https://www.riseupandsing.org/songbooks/rise-up-singing)."

That expression appears in [the lyric of Summertime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summertime_%28George_Gershwin_song%29#Lyrics), from Porgy and Bess. I wonder whether that's the whole story of the phrase (it was created by Gershwin), or whether the phrase has a longer history, such as (for example) use in actual folk music or spirituals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, that specific phrase does indeed originate with "Summertime." It's a peculiarity of lullabies that they are intended to comfort infants, and yet many of them deal with dark and morbid themes.  In this case, the phrase "rise up singing" is a description of death as a joyful release from life, so the song is really an [Ecclesiastes-like juxtaposition](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes+9%3A7-10&version=ESV) of the sensual pleasures of "now" giving way to the inevitability of mortality.

> Summertime, and the livin' is easy
>   Fish are jumpin' and the cotton is high
>   Oh, your daddy's rich and your ma is good-lookin'
>   So hush, little baby, don't you cry
>
> One of these mornings you're gonna **rise up singing**
>   And you'll spread your wings and you'll take to the sky
>   But till that morning, there ain't nothin' can harm you
>   With daddy and mammy standin' by

This lyric was written by DuBose Heyward (music by George Gershwin) in direct imitation of black American spirituals and lullabies.  The theme of death-as-release is particularly common in slave-era spirituals, where the brutal wretchedness of life as a slave was often contrasted to hopes for a better afterlife.  (Compare also the similar lyrics in "[I'll Fly Away](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/alisonkrauss/illflyaway.html)" and ["Walk around Heaven"](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/18712597/The+Mighty+Clouds+of+Joy/Walk+Around+Heaven) --among churchgoing black Americans, funerals are still most often referred to as "homegoing celebrations.")

A particular inspiration for "Summertime" is said to be the more authentic lullaby "All My Trials", which does share this central theme:

> Hush little baby, don't you cry,
>   You know your mother was born to die
>   All my trials, Lord, soon be over
>   Too late my brothers, too late
>   But never mind
>   All my trials, Lord soon be over

Another potential inspiration is the well-known lullaby "All the Pretty Little Horses," which, like "Summertime", is said to be narrated by a slave woman to her master's pampered child.  "Pretty Horses" has a particularly dark additional subtext in which the narrator describes how her own child must be neglected as she is forced to care for another mother's child instead.  A lot of the power and appeal of both songs is the sense of a well of pain and suffering underlying superficially celebratory lyrics.

> Hush a bye, don't you cry,
>   Go to sleep you little baby. 
>   when you wake you shall have
>   all the pretty little horses..
>
> Way down yonder
>   In the meadow
>   Poor little baby crying "Mammy!"
>   Birds and butterflies
>   pecking out his eyes
>   Poor little baby crying "Mammy!"

All these songs can be found in that excellent collection of which you speak.